A tricky integral inequality in analytical mechanics proof
I've found the following in my reference book "Analytical mechanics, an introduction" by Fasano, Marmi, 2006 edition.
Formula (3) appears in chapter 9, paragraph 3, example 9.7, page 314.
The function $\eta(t)$ is $\in \mathcal{C}^2[0,\theta]$ with $\eta(0)=\eta(\theta)=0$.
Given the integral
$$\int_0^\theta{(\dot\eta^2-\omega^2\eta^2) \mathrm{d}t}\tag{1}$$
and given the following inequality
$$|\eta(t)|=\left|\int_0^t{\dot\eta(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau}\right|\leq\sqrt{t}\left[\int_0^t\dot\eta^2(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau\right]^\frac{1}{2}\tag{2}$$
we have that
$$\int_0^\theta{(\dot\eta^2-\omega^2\eta^2) \mathrm{d}t}\geq(1-\frac{1}{2}\omega^2\theta^2)\left[\int_0^\theta\dot\eta^2(t)\mathrm{d}t\right]^\frac{1}{2}\tag{3}$$
I know how to derive 2, as it is a consequence of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality applied to the inner product of $\dot\eta$ and $1$, $\int_0^t{\dot\eta(\tau)1\mathrm{d}\tau}$.
What is not clear to me is how we go from 2 to 3.
Please note that the aim of the text is to prove that there are values of $\theta$ for which the integral at 1 is always non negative, as $$\frac{1}{2}m\int_0^\theta{\dot\eta^2-\omega^2\eta^2 \mathrm{d}t}$$ is the variation of the hamiltonian action of an harmonic oscillator for synchronous perturbations $\eta$.

@D.W. looks better now? I've also incorporated the typo fix to my trascription of the formula in formula 3, as now I am citing directly the reference book.

Looks great, thank you!

Your inequality (3) is wrong there shouldn’t be a square root on the RHS (otherwise the scaling is off); also the upper limit should be $\theta$.

By using $(2)$, and the fact that $t\leq \tau$ implies $\int_0^t\dot{\eta}^2\leq\int_0^{\tau}\dot{\eta}^2$, we get
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\theta}\eta^2(t)\,dt&\leq \int_0^{\theta}t\cdot \left(\int_0^t\dot{\eta}^2\right)\,dt
\leq \int_0^{\theta}t\,dt\cdot\int_0^{\theta}\dot{\eta}^2=\frac{\theta^2}{2}\cdot\int_0^{\theta}\dot{\eta}^2
\end{align}
Now, multiplying by $-\omega^2$ (which flips the inequality direction) immediately yields
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\theta}(\dot{\eta}^2-\omega^2\eta^2)\,dt&\geq \left(1-\frac{\omega^2\theta^2}{2}\right)\int_0^{\theta}\dot{\eta}^2.
\end{align}
In fact, this derivation only required $\eta\in C^1([0,\theta])$ with $\eta(0)=0$, so we can actually repeat this argument to each of the restrictions $\eta|_{[0,\theta_0]}$, so that for all $\theta_0\in [0,\theta]$, we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\theta_0}(\dot{\eta}^2-\omega^2\eta^2)\,dt&\geq \left(1-\frac{\omega^2\theta_0^2}{2}\right)\int_0^{\theta_0}\dot{\eta}^2.\tag{3’}
\end{align}

Edit: Scaling.
Intuitively, if $\eta$ has some units $(\ddot{\smile})$, then the LHS of your inequality (3) has units of $\frac{(\ddot{\smile})^2}{\text{Time}}$ while the RHS of (3) has units of $\sqrt{\frac{(\ddot{\smile})^2}{\text{Time}}}$, so we shouldn’t be able to compare them (especially since the constant prefactor of $1-\frac{\omega^2\theta^2}{2}$ is dimensionless). This tells us the inequality has to be wrong in general.
Here’s a more detailed explanation of the scaling argument showing your (3) is wrong. Calling the integrals appearing on the left and right $L(\eta),R(\eta)$ respectively, and $c:=1-\frac{\omega^2\theta^2}{2}$, we have the inequality $L(\eta)\geq c [R(\eta)]^{1/2}$ for all $\eta$ in a suitable vector space $V$ of functions.
Ok, if the inequality holds for $\eta$, then it had better hold for all multiples of $\eta$, so for all $\lambda\in\Bbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
L(\lambda\eta)&\geq c[R(\lambda\eta)]^{1/2},
\end{align}
and thus
\begin{align}
\lambda^2 L(\eta)&\geq |\lambda|\cdot c[R(\eta)]^{1/2}.
\end{align}
In particular, for all $\lambda>0$ and all $\eta\in V$,
\begin{align}
\lambda L(\eta)&\geq c[R(\eta)]^{1/2}.
\end{align}
This is absurd because if $\eta$ is a function for which $R(\eta)\neq 0$ (and clearly such $\eta$ exists), then by taking the limit $\lambda\to 0^+$, we get the absurd inequality that $0\geq c[R(\eta)]^{1/2}>0$, i.e $0>0$.
More generally, given $p,q>0$, in order for there to exist a constant $c_{p,q}>0$ such that for all $\eta\in V$, $[L(\eta)]^p\geq c_{p,q}[R(\eta)]^q$, it is necessary that $p=q$ (and the fact that the corrected (3’) holds shows that it is sufficient). The proof of this necessity is similar to the scaling argument above.

thanks. the upper limit was my fault. what do you mean by "the scaling is off"?

@ebenezer I have edited with a more detailed explanation of the scaling issue. This is actually a fundamental ‘consistency check’ and helps to rule out ‘bad inequalities’ and it can also suggest good ones. For example it tells us the correct exponents for many things like Holder’s inequality (i.e why we need $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$) and Sobolev inequalities etc. See this chat history and the link to Terry Tao’s blog page for more discussion along these lines.

thanks a lot for this further explanation, it adds a lot of value to what was just a typo fix!
